# lock screen rotation but detect it anyway

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I m building an app which an a main layout in portrait format

I locking orientation with

```
 setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

However, I need to detect screen orientation changes anyway because I want to load another Activity if the screen is rotated.

How to do that ?

I tryed onConfigurationChanged but it s never called.

Comment: did you add the desired configuration change in manifest?

Answer (score 0):

Some things to look at if onConfigurationChanged isn't firing:

When you declare the manifest, make sure you have defined at least orientation and screenSize for the activity configChanges. Like this:

```
<activity android:name="com.test.act" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
```

Make sure the device doesn't have rotation blocked. For example if you are using a Nexus 7:

http://www.howtogeek.com/120056/how-to-enable-landscape-orientation-on-the-nexus-7s-home-screen/